# Indirect reference to thisRow in Excel table

Tags: excel

The situation: I have an automatic procedure for gathering data from different input-sheets and presenting in a pivot-friendly format. It appears others are in need of the same data, though they want it formatted slightly differently (and they are not friends with excel). I therefor have a version of my table formatted as they want it (with empty columns where my extract does not contain any data).

The table (both) is one line for each department for each year for each cost/income  (from now, cost) category. The raw data contains the cost for each year, though some of the users want it to be cost delta from initial year. I want:
One column for raw cost (X). One column for delta cost (Y). One output column (Z) that contains one of those two values, depending on dropdown selection. The first two columns are situated to the right of the "select with mouse and copy these"-columns, so that I dont need to teach the other users how to select non-adjecent columns :P (just letting u know the level of understanding i have to work with here)

Now the naive approach to this would be to have an if-statement in column Z like this:

```
=IF(selected_Calc="Use raw cost";[@[X]];[@[Y]])
```

Alternatively nest more ifs (one for "Use difference to 2019", and potentially add more nesting if more ways to show the value should appear in future)

This works. However, it isnt as elegant as I would like it, and if I indeed end up with more ways to calculate this for other people, it will be a lot of nested ifs.

I was therefore considering something like this:

```
=INDIRECT("[@["INDEX(mapTab_out;match(selected_Calc;mapTab_in;0))&]]")
```

But this gives a #ref,  and tbh i didn't really expect it to work.

The idea is though: .

- Have a range mapTab_in. This has the different selections for the dropdown box.
- Have the adjecent range mapTab_out. This has the name of the column (X,Y...) that contains the desired calculation)
- Have in column Z a formula for selecting which column's (X,Y...) value is to be displayed in Z

The google-stuff I have found so far all seem interested in using the indirect function from outside the table, and usually want to sum an entire column. I have used this in the past. The "ThisRow" things like using @ dont seem to work with indirect though. Any ideas, or have I simply made some beginner-error in my formula?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's in the same table, you can take advantage of implicit intersection and simply use:

```
=INDEX(Tablename,,MATCH(selected_Calc,Tablename[#Headers],0))
```

where selected_Calc is the name of the column you want back. (You could make that the result of a further INDEX/MATCH if you want to use a lookup table for some reason.)